# Selecting records from entire table based on results of a subset

Tags: sql-server

Table has multiple columns. Let us say a sales invoice. Based on a value in a specific column (not equal to blank) I can select the invoices that were adjusted in the last month. transactions that occurred in the current month. Now I want to find the history for each of these invoices - I want a record of all the times the invoice was touched (for example to add or delete a line or change the quantity or price etc). The table contains all these previous transactions. I want to identify the history of the transaction based on the adjustment made last month.

How would I write a query?

Comment: do you have a table recording the history for these invoices? where each row represents one adjustment? it's not clear what tables you have to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've provided very little actual information about your situation, I'm going to assume you want a technique you can apply, rather than a real answer. So here's the technique:

```
SELECT I.* FROM InvoiceHistory AS I
    WHERE I.InvoiceID IN (
        SELECT InvoiceID FROM InvoiceHistory AS I2
           WHERE SomeField IS NOT NULL)
```